# Zero Knowledge Proofs for Microsoft SEAL (Homomorphic Encryption)

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, homomorphic-encryption, paillier

I am working on a system involving multiple parties performing homomorphic cryptographic operations using Microsoft SEAL (BFV). Because of the nature of the system, it would be preferable for the parties to share zero-knowledge proofs of correctness for the operations performed.

I am specifically interested in a non-interactive ZKP to attest the correct encoding and encryption of a plaintext (where the plaintext and secret key are not shared) and a proof of correct decoding and decryption (where the secret key is not shared). It would also be ideal for ZKPs to be provided for addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication operations (between homomorphically encrypted ciphertexts).

I have been able to find such proofs for Paillier (partially homomorphic) but can't seem to find any references for SEAL.